# ORA-01084: invalid argument in OCI call goes away after iisreset

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, iis

There is no change in code or stored procedure since I changed it last 2 days back. 
Everything was working fine. 
Today when I executed same piece of code it started throwing

> "ORA-01084: invalid argument in OCI call".

After 4-5 attempts when I restarted IIS it started working without any problem.

Can anybody shed some light on why this error stopped after IIS reset?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: What query did you attempt to execute?

Comment: There are multiple insert queries in the Stored Procedure. One of them uses XMLTYPE but there is a check to see if value of input parameter is not null before this Insert.

Comment: The stored procedure was executing without any issue from oracle's sql developer but failing from the code.